# Intellij Idea 13 not showing "Update Resources and classes" option

Tags: intellij-idea

Running a Tomcat 6 Server. On clicking **Update** option, I get the following options -

[image]

The option to **Update Resources and classes** in no more shown. Not to update JSPs, I have restart the server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to deploy **exploded** artifact, after this you can choose "Update resources" or "Update classes and resources" option.